# If $n$ is odd, do the eigenvalues need to by multiplied by $-1$ if I use $\det(\lambda I-A)$ instead of $\det(A - \lambda I)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have seen the characteristic polynomial written as $f(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-A)$ or $f(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)$.

By determinant rules $\det(\lambda I-A)\iff (-1)^n\cdot\det(A-\lambda I)$. That means that if $n$ is even it does not matter which formula I use. If $n$ is odd, do my eigenvalues need to by multiplied by $-1$ if I use $f(\lambda)=\det(\lambda I-A)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The eigenvalues of $A$ are the *zeroes* of the characteristic polynomial. It doesn't matter whether you take the characteristic polynomial to be $\det(A -\lambda I)$ or $\det(\lambda I - A)$; they differ by at most a factor of $-1$, so their zeroes are the same.